# Probability of hitting times for discrete random walks

Tags: probability

I am reading this paper here on "hitting time distributions for discrete random walks" [https://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/monthly753-756-hofstad.pdf](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Erhofstad/monthly753-756-hofstad.pdf).

Looking at equation (9):

$$P_k(T_0 = n) = \frac{k}{n} P_k(S_n = 0)$$

This equation describes the probability of a discrete random walk (with equal probabilities of step size +1 or -1) first reaching the origin (i.e. position=0) at time=n, given that the random walk started at position=k at time=0.

I am trying to find out how to calculate $P_k(S_n = 0)$. That is, what is the probability that in $k$ steps, the sum of all steps that have been taken sum to 0.

I tried to represent this as an easier problem. For example, suppose you have a coin with probability 0.5 of +1 and probability 0.5 of -1. Suppose your current score is 5. What is the probability of getting a score of $M$ in $K$ turns?

Here is the logic I used in this question:

- Define $N$ as the number of turns where you get +1. This means that after $K$ turns, your total score can be given by : $5 + N - (K - N) = 5 + 2N - K$
- We want the total score after $K$ turns to be equal to $M$. This means that $M=5 + 2N - K$
- Solving for $N$, we get $N = (K + M - 5) / 2$ . This result surprised me because it seems that there is only a single value of $N$ which will give you a score of $M$ in this situation (I would have thought that there should be more).
- Now, the probability of getting these $N$ required steps (in $K$ trials) can be understood as a Binomial Probability:

$$P(N) = \binom{K}{N} * (0.5)^N * (0.5)^{K-N} = \binom{K}{N} * (0.5)^K$$

Does my analysis (i.e. $P(N)$) correspond to what the authors of this paper meant by $P_k(S_n = 0)$?